# Compiling C++11 on g++ 4.4.7 in Red Hat linux

Tags: c++11, compilation, g++, redhat

I have already tried:

```
g++ -std=c++11 my_file.cpp -o my_prog
g++ -std=c++0x ...
g++ -std=gnu++0x ...
```

and I keep getting this message:

```
error: unrecognized command line option
```

Comment: g++ 4.4.7 doesn't support c++11 does it?

Comment: What does `which g++` report? And what does `g++ -v` report?

Answer (score 7):

[C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

From there you can see that C++11 is supported since gcc 4.7 and gcc 4.4 has C++0x support.

Quote from [Status of Experimental C++0x Support in GCC 4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html):

> GCC provides experimental support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard,
>   C++0x. This support can be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
>   compiler options; the former disables GNU extensions.

So it should work with `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your problem is:

```
[11:51am][wlynch@apple /tmp] cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
[11:51am][wlynch@apple /tmp] g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) 
[11:51am][wlynch@apple /tmp] g++ -std=c++0x simple.cc 
[11:51am][wlynch@apple /tmp]
```